# Is it OK to bring attention to your answer to an old question if your answer is better?

Tags: discussion, answers

### Theoretically:

- There is a popular (~2500 views) inactive 2-years-old question with
  a few answers about some framework (or whatever)
- Other answers provide solutions that require from 2 to several
  lines of code to achieve what the OP is asking, also using some other
  classes of this framework (or whatever)
- My answer provides a one parameter solution, without changing anything else in the OP's code
- Looking at other answers I can assume that my solution didn't come with some new version of framework, plus the question does not specify any version restriction

### Situation:

- My answer is the lowest with score of zero and probably won't even be seen by those who rely on the accepted answer
- I do not want to put a bounty on it, because my current amount of reputation will be cut by ~60%
- OP has ~100 questions and it's been several days from posting, so I can assume that either he didn't see the notification of a new answer or just couldn't check it for some reason

### Options

1. The most simple - **leave it as is**, possibly in some days/weeks/month my solution will be spotted
2. Notify the OP in comments and ask him to check my solution
3. Notify other participants that I have a solution that may be more elegant and ask them to check it

**So my question is:** Should I do anything at all in this kind of situation?
Because as I see it notifying everyone is some kind of rep-seeking and possibly will be very annoying and it seems like an unacceptable way of using Stack Overflow. On the other hand my solution can save someone some time.

Comment: I'd say the answer is no, there is no need to do anything here, unless the top answer is hopelessly wrong or has security implication.

Comment: *better* is a bit subjective, specially on your own creations ... I would just leave that the community to judge. If you can't resist the urge to bring your answer in the spotlight at least call it an *alternative approach* instead of *better/elegant*.

Comment: @rene "better" just was used as a least aggressive word in my vocabulary. I am not saying that my solution is alpha-solution, it just requires less efforts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP will automatically be notified that there's a new answer to his/her question, so 2. is not necessary. He/she might conclude your answer is the best solution, and if so, accept it. This will put your answer on the top of the list, where it's most visible.

I have seen some instances of 3.; while it is not forbidden, some people may react badly on it. The other answerers might not even have the same problem as the OP did (but just happened to know the answer). In that case, you're just wasting their time.

Of course, 1. is always a good option. When I search for a solution to a problem on Stack Overflow, I will usually look at all non-downvoted solutions (unless there are like 20 or so). Elegant one-liners like your answer are always worth a try - though they might be less flexible than the other options. If it is really the best solution, it will rise to the top – just be patient.

Comment: For 3. it comes down to wording ... *better / elegant / improved / superior* are words I would avoid. Being humble raises the changes of success...

Comment: @rene 'elegant' is an exception here - it doesn't compare one solution to another (but 'More elegant' does)

Comment: That is the problem with non-native speakers like my self: I don't get that distinction....

Comment: In my question I pointed that it is possible that OP just didn`t noticed the notification (answer there for a week and OP was online all this days), so 2. is just for one-try-renotificate. I had the same thoughts your answer provided, just was hoping that there is some common standart set of actions

Comment: The OP might have left SO long ago (as is often the case); however, in that case leaving a comment won't have any effect either.