# Downvoted and censored after asking for feedback in the chat

Tags: support, downvotes, specific-answer, deleted-comments

According to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328133/is-it-ok-to-bring-attention-to-your-answer-to-an-old-question-if-your-answer-is), if you have a new, answer to an old question and you believe it's better than existing answers (or offers a solution not available at the time), it's OK to notify other answerers of your solution. It's specifically "not forbidden":

> while it is not forbidden, some people may react badly on it.

I've done that for [this 2010 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript) and asked in the JavaScript chat for ["up/down votes as [y'all] see fit"](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/32828218#32828218). Indeed, some people have reacted badly to that. I got -7 in short order, without comments, plus one delete vote, and all my comments on the other answers were deleted.

Is [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript/39477406#39477406) that terrible to deserve -7, and to be deleted, and for the code snippet in it to no longer be runnable? (Yep, that's what happens, apparently, if your answer gets enough downvotes, presumably to prevent malware from being spread.)

[image: Revenge downvotes]

**UPDATE** Some people didn't seem to grok that the OP wanted the time in the local time zone. If you look at the sample they provided, it's this:

```
<abbr title="2010-04-02T14:12:07">
```

That's not ISO8601, which has a 'Z' suffix for the UTC timezone. That's a a time without any specified timezone, which means a local time.

Thanks again for the downvotes here as well and for the comments admonishing me that my answer was off-topic. Anyway, I gave a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript/39480351#39480351), because my goal was to help. I have enough rep to not care about downvotes, but not enough zen to not care about jerks.

Comment: So... You found a note observing that a certain action might cause some people to react badly, took that action, and found that some people reacted badly to it?

Comment: @Shog9: I expected those answerers to potentially not be gentlemen in the "let the best answer win" sense and react badly, but not the folks on chat.

Comment: OP didn't mention anything about converting the date to the user's timezone.

Comment: Also, please don't call deleting comments "censoring". Comments are deleted only if they don't contain any useful information.

Comment: @Gothdo: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript/16177227#16177227) also recommends converting to the local timezone, because it's the sensible thing to do (the string is a tooltip, and you don't want the user to do date math in their head). That answer didn't get 8 downvotes.

Comment: From chat: `Up/down vote as you see fit.`  Asking for votes isn't really kosher anywhere on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: there is also no such thing as "deserving" of a score. A post doesn't deserve "-4" or "+3". A post deserves to be voted on based on the post itself. If 7 people saw your post and decided it was bad... then you get -7.

Comment: @Gothdo: my comments contained useful information - a link to a better solution.

Comment: @DanDascalescu wait... so the only thing these comments was (stop me if I'm wrong) is "there is a new answer to this question you should look at?" (or something of that nature. Then, at the SECOND you post them, the answerer gets notified. At the second the answerer is notified, your comment isn't useful anymore.

Comment: Could you possibly entertain the idea that it's not that great of an answer? It doesn't actually explain what the code does, or why you did it in the fashion in which you did it. For instance, creating a new date from the old one and applying the offset does not require that much code: `new Date(d.valueOf() - (d.getTimezoneOffset()/60000));` (I'm not sure what is wrong with "/60" calculations) or `var n = new Date(d); n.setMinutes(n.getMinutes() - d.getTimezoneOffset());`.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: yours is an even better answer, and I'd totally upvote it if you posted it. Wish others had the same attitude.

Comment: Asking in chat "plz upvote my post" is as bad as posting "plz give me teh codez" question. And (probably without knowing that) that is exactly what you did.

Comment: You literally asked for downvotes, and yet you are surprised to receive them?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan: I've fixed your answer, credited you, explained why the OP actually did want the time in the local time zone, and posted a [new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573521/how-do-i-output-an-iso-8601-formatted-string-in-javascript/39480351#39480351).

Comment: "Some people didn't seem to grok that the OP wanted the time in the local time zone" - that's a very large leap of faith, considering that the OP, *in the question*, used `getUTC*` functions *and* accepted an answer returning the date in UTC.

Comment: _"Downvoted and censored after asking for feedback in the chat"_:  You didn't ask for feedback. You asked for votes. You got votes.

Comment: That answer is overly complicated and many of the others provide better solutions, so it's not surprising that begging for votes got you a pile of downvotes.

Comment: ISO 8601 does not require a 'Z' suffix, and it does not necessarily specify a time in UTC. It is perfectly capable of expressing local time.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Even though it isn't strictly forbidden, I probably wouldn't bother pointing a bunch of people in a chat room to a new answer to an old question. As you've learned, people are just as likely to downvote it as upvote it. Why? Probably because it isn't immediately useful *to them*.

Most of the time that I upvote a question or answer, it's because it helped me solve a problem that I was working on. I arrived at the question from a Google search, not from a chat room or a social network. (Sure, occasionally someone will share [a true gem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/1288), but those are the exceptions.) When I visit a post that someone linked to, I'm most likely to just not vote on it at all because I'm not invested in it.

The best options when answering an old question are to either ask people for feedback (as already mentioned), or just wait for people to naturally find your answer. Your answer seems fine, but it's not going to get the 300+ upvotes it needs to zip to the top of that page any time soon. That will only happen slowly, as people who need an answer to that question come across it and find your answer useful.

Answer (score 50):

I'm gonna just post this screenshot from the link you gave:

[image: Hey y'all, I believe this new answer I posted is actually the best for the question. Up/down vote as you see fit. (in sidebar: join 50 users in this room now)]

You asked ~50 people to vote up or down as they saw fit. It would appear that, to date, 8 of them have done so.

Perhaps next time you point a large group of people at an answer you should ask them for their advice, or suggestions on how it might be made clearly better than existing answers, instead of posting an open invitation to vote? Folks here tend to be quite literal at times, especially when doing so carries the promise of delicious irony.

Comment: In other words, when there's an opportunity to be a jerk on SO, be one! Who cares about bubbling up useful answers.

Comment: @DanDascalescu In other words, don't ask for votes on your posts.  Users will vote as they see fit.

Comment: Your assumption here is that local times in ISO format are... useful, @Dan. Perhaps they are. But you didn't ask for anyone's opinion on this, you just asked them to vote. I'd have to assume that no one who has ever needed this was in attendance.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Apparently the people who downvoted don't consider your answer useful. And if someone downvotes your answer because of that, that's definitely not being a jerk—they're just expressing their opinion.

Comment: @Shog9 Or simply that it wasn't relevant to the question at hand.

Comment: @Servy: For user-facing timestamps, of course you want answers in the local timezone, unless all your users are admins, or some other rare target market. You don't want users to do timezone math in their head.

Comment: @Dan ... how do *you* know what I want or don't want my users to do?

Comment: @TinyGiant: look at the OP in the question. It displays a relative time, "A couple days ago". That means the users are "casual users", and don't want precise time information by default.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Not necessarily.  There are plenty of times where posting server time is appropriate, but regardless, the point is *the question isn't asking how to post the time using the local timezone*, the quesiton is asking about a particular problem they're having posting the UTC time, so you telling them how to post the local time *when they need the UTC time* for whatever reason that is, may be deemed as not  useful by those that voted.  If they were asking how to display the time *absent any context* than assuming they meant local, rather than UTC, would likely be warranted.

Comment: we're grasping at straws at this point and arguing irrelevant facts/opinions. Point is, you asked for votes, and you got them.

Comment: @KevinB Now he's asking for an explanation of those votes, and he's getting that.

Comment: @KevinB: silly me then. But why didn't anyone care to leave a comment for their downvote?

Comment: because no one is ever forced to do so and no one thought it necessary to explain the downvotes, the tooltip was enough.

Comment: @Dan The majority of your answer is about converting it to local time. That part does not answer the question at all, it is completely irrelevant. The part of your answer that may or may not answer the question has no explanation. All in all, it is not very useful, with regards to the question asked. If you were answering a question  "How do I convert this server time to local time?" your answer would be applicable.

Comment: @TinyGiant:  [It'd actually be a dupe.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17415579/1079354)  So, it may be the case of an answer being created to a question that was never asked.

Comment: Also, commenting on votes is kind of the opposite of what we do here. We vote on content, and comment on content (when we think improvements can be made, or clarifications are necessary). We do not comment on votes.

Comment: You didn't ask for comments, @Dan. Asking for comments - instead of votes - would've probably gotten you a lot more of a useful response. So... Be careful what you ask for, I guess?

Comment: Good point, that clears everything. OK if I delete my answer now and stop wasting everyone's time? Also, @MikeMcCaughan gave an even better answer in the question comments.

Comment: I feel bad that it was handled the way it was, after all you were just trying to help... but... that is what you asked for... and people responded literally.

Comment: @Gothdo: the OP did give a sample output, which was in the local timezone format. I've updated my question.

Comment: You came in chat, dumped your answer in there, then didn't respond for 45 minutes, when one of the first replies to you was: _"@DanDascalescu Did you really just come here asking for votes?"_. What did you expect?

Answer (score 30):

> and all my comments on the other answers were deleted.

This may be a significant source of early downvotes. You went to every other answer in the thread to leave a comment to *advertise* your new answer. **Don't do that**. Don't use the comments below *other people's posts* to advertise your own "better" content. That will *never* be well received.

It's also worth noting that there were coincidentally timed downvotes on most of the answers where you left comments. Again, downvoting everybody *else* and then linking to your own answer isn't going to win you any friends.

To make matters worse, you were sometimes **actually insulting** to the existing answers when you left your self-advertising comments. There is absolutely no mystery here as to why you were downvoted.

Here is an example of the comments you left below somebody else's existing answer:

[image]